# How do I upload a file to Google Drive using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-drive-api

I am making a Flutter mobile app and am trying to save images taken with the camera to a specific Google drive account for storage. I have obtained a service account JSON file from my Google account to authenticate.

This is the code I am using:

```
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'package:googleapis/drive/v3.dart' as ga;
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';

uploadFileToGoogleDrive(io.File fileToUpload) async {

  // send authorization to access Google Drive
  // from https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis_auth

  ServiceAccountCredentials accountCredentials = new ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson({
//my service account JSON information goes here
  });
  List<String> scopes = [ga.DriveApi.DriveFileScope, ga.DriveApi.DriveScope];


 
    try {
      // authenticates with Google Drive with our service account credentials
      AuthClient client = await clientViaServiceAccount(
          accountCredentials, scopes);

      ga.DriveApi drive = ga.DriveApi(client);
      ga.File file = ga.File(); // create new file record to upload to Drive
      try {
        file.name = 'image.jpg';
        
        ga.File response = await drive.files.create(file, uploadMedia: ga.Media(
            fileToUpload.openRead(), fileToUpload.lengthSync()));
   
        print('uploaded with a file size of: ${response.size}');
      } on Exception catch (e) {
        print('upload error: $e');
      }
      client.close();
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print('credentials error: $e');
    }
  
}
```

The file I am uploading has a size of 24095. No error messages are returned. The returned 'response' has a Google drive file ID but a size of null, and I cannot the uploaded file in the Google Drive when logging in from the web. What is the correct way to upload this file using the Google Drive API?

Comment: why google drive ?
why not google storage / Amazon web service S3 ?

Comment: Have you checked the googleapis example on how to [upload and download](https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis_examples/blob/master/drive_upload_download_console/bin/main.dart)?

Comment: @dwikurniantom I had thought that Google Drive would have been easier since I was more familiar with it, but it doesn't seem to be so I'll look into those alternatives. Thanks!

Comment: @Kessy Thanks! I had been following some tutorials on Medium but hadn't found that one.

Answer (score 18):

Its easy but you have to go through a series of Steps to complete it.

**1. Enable Google Drive API**

click on the link to google console :
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library?project=diary-app-339509

- Create a new project and enable Drive API on the project.
- Create an OAuth client Id for android and IOS
- You will have to fill a lot of details to create it , read through the page and fill it
- copy Client ID for future use

[create project and enable API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTZgI.png)

[Create OAuth client id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8Qcd.png)

[form to fill to make OAuth client id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvo27.png)

**2. Make project available for external use .**

[for testing add test user email address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIOMZ.png)

*Now comes the coding part on flutter*

**3. Add the following packages to *pubspec.yaml***

```
  googleapis: ^7.0.0
  googleapis_auth: ^1.3.0
  flutter_secure_storage: ^5.0.2
  url_launcher: ^6.0.0-nullsafety
```

**4. Get authentication from google and store the Auth details for future auths**

Use the following class for storing Auth Details

```
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';

class SecureStorage {
  final storage = FlutterSecureStorage();

  //Save Credentials
  Future saveCredentials(AccessToken token, String refreshToken) async {
    print(token.expiry.toIso8601String());
    await storage.write(key: "type", value: token.type);
    await storage.write(key: "data", value: token.data);
    await storage.write(key: "expiry", value: token.expiry.toString());
    await storage.write(key: "refreshToken", value: refreshToken);
  }

  //Get Saved Credentials
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> getCredentials() async {
    var result = await storage.readAll();
    if (result.isEmpty) return null;
    return result;
  }

  //Clear Saved Credentials
  Future clear() {
    return storage.deleteAll();
  }
}
```

**5.Finally use this class for saving your file to Drive**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:googleapis/drive/v3.dart' as ga;
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;
import 'package:personal_diary/app/utils/secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

const _clientId = "YOUR CLIENT ID FROM GOOGLE CONSOLE";
const _scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'];

class GoogleDrive {
  final storage = SecureStorage();
  //Get Authenticated Http Client
  Future<http.Client> getHttpClient() async {
    //Get Credentials
    var credentials = await storage.getCredentials();
    if (credentials == null) {
      //Needs user authentication
      var authClient = await clientViaUserConsent(
          ClientId(_clientId),_scopes, (url) {
        //Open Url in Browser
        launch(url);
      });
      //Save Credentials
      await storage.saveCredentials(authClient.credentials.accessToken,
          authClient.credentials.refreshToken!);
      return authClient;
    } else {
      print(credentials["expiry"]);
      //Already authenticated
      return authenticatedClient(
          http.Client(),
          AccessCredentials(
              AccessToken(credentials["type"], credentials["data"],
                  DateTime.tryParse(credentials["expiry"])!),
              credentials["refreshToken"],
              _scopes));
    }
  }

// check if the directory forlder is already available in drive , if available return its id
// if not available create a folder in drive and return id
//   if not able to create id then it means user authetication has failed
  Future<String?> _getFolderId(ga.DriveApi driveApi) async {
    final mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
    String folderName = "personalDiaryBackup";

    try {
      final found = await driveApi.files.list(
        q: "mimeType = '$mimeType' and name = '$folderName'",
        $fields: "files(id, name)",
      );
      final files = found.files;
      if (files == null) {
        print("Sign-in first Error");
        return null;
      }

      // The folder already exists
      if (files.isNotEmpty) {
        return files.first.id;
      }

      // Create a folder
      ga.File folder = ga.File();
      folder.name = folderName;
      folder.mimeType = mimeType;
      final folderCreation = await driveApi.files.create(folder);
      print("Folder ID: ${folderCreation.id}");

      return folderCreation.id;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }

  
  uploadFileToGoogleDrive(File file) async {
    var client = await getHttpClient();
    var drive = ga.DriveApi(client);
    String? folderId =  await _getFolderId(drive);
    if(folderId == null){
      print("Sign-in first Error");
    }else {
      ga.File fileToUpload = ga.File();
      fileToUpload.parents = [folderId];
      fileToUpload.name = p.basename(file.absolute.path);
      var response = await drive.files.create(
        fileToUpload,
        uploadMedia: ga.Media(file.openRead(), file.lengthSync()),
      );
      print(response);
    }

  }




}
```

Comment: Does this solution avoid Google login? Or the user still needs to login with a Google account in order to be able to upload the file?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out in addition to enabling the API and creating the service account, I ALSO needed to share the folder I wanted to upload to with the service account email address from the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error recently and I tried hard and finally I solved it. The error is due to SHA-1 key mismatch. Please go to your Android directory and use the ./gradlew signingReport => command in it.