# Is there any working tutorial for using google-api's with flutter for android

Tags: android, flutter, google-api

I am trying to use google drive API with flutter, testing on an android real device. I followed some youtube videos and medium blogs, i couldn't get it working.If there is any tutorial that you know, please post here.

I am currently using these packages googleapis: ^7.0.0, googleapis_auth: ^1.3.0.

I am stuck with an error that says about redirect_uri

[image]

This is a part of the code

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:google_drive_upload/helpers/constants.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/drive/v3.dart' as gdrive;
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class DriveService {
  List<String> _scopes = [gdrive.DriveApi.driveScope];

  getHttpClient() async {
    return await clientViaUserConsent(ClientId(clientId), _scopes, prompt);
  }

  prompt(String url) {
    launch(url);
  }

  upload(File file) async {
    var client = await getHttpClient();
    var drive = gdrive.DriveApi(client);
    var res = await drive.files.create(
      gdrive.File(),
      uploadMedia: gdrive.Media(file.openRead(), file.lengthSync()),
    );

    print('Response here ${res.toJson()}');
  }
}
```

I couldn't find redirect_uri in Oauth client in Oauth credentials for android (its available for web clients though).

Please help me to resolve this, been stuck here since 2 days :(

**Edit 1**
Tried with new fresh app with comoletely random appname so android domain won't clash, still same result.

Comment: looks like you are using code designed for a web app and not an android app.  Either find the android code or create a web app credentials on google developer console.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/65784077/1841839

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70880091/6661043

Comment: Hey i tried the steps given in that answer, i am getting same error with different port numbers. By the way my domain of android buid is com.example.google_drive_demo_app, does it has to do anything with it? because the youtube video i followed has his own domain