# Flutter Upload a file to a given Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I am working on a project that requires to upload some users' files to a Google Drive.

I saw some solutions, such as [How do I upload a file to Google Drive using Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65784077/how-do-i-upload-a-file-to-google-drive-using-flutter), requires user sign in.

Is there anyway I can upload files from all the users to a predefine Google Drive and no need to ask users to sign in.

Thank you.